# SQL Server: Selecting using count and Case

Tags: sql-server

Hello a client of ours has requested a "count(values) as NAME"
now on it's own that would be nice and simple but what they are asking for is

3 seperate columns where the defining factor is an "ID"
with a count for values for instance:

Count(CC where CC in ('A','B','C') 
adding up to something like this

```
select case((select count(CC where CC in ('A','B','C') AB,
count(CC where CC in ('D','E') DE and id = 1234),
case((select count(CC where CC in ('Z','X','Y') XY,
count(CC where CC in ('W','G') WG and id = 1235)
```

Can anyone think of anyway to make this possible?

```
Sample Data
ID,  CC
1234 A
1234 B
1234 C
1234 A
1235 B
1235 B
1234 A
1235 C
1234 A
1234 B
1235 C
1234 A
1234 B
1235 B
1234 A
1235 C
```

Expected Output

```
CC   ID:1234    ID:1235
A     6           0
B     3           3
C     1           1
```

( sorry to say Dynamic SQL is out the window on this one, the software the client uses to pull the information does not allow for temporary tables, updates, inserts or deletes)

Comment: Have you sample data and an expected result?

Comment: The prohibition of temp tables does not preclude the use of dynamic SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use dynamic SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE TestTbl (ID INT,  CC VARCHAR(10));
INSERT INTO TestTbl VALUES
 (1234,'A')
,(1234,'B')
,(1234,'C')
,(1234,'A')
,(1235,'B')
,(1235,'B')
,(1234,'A')
,(1235,'C')
,(1234,'A')
,(1234,'B')
,(1235,'C')
,(1234,'A')
,(1234,'B')
,(1235,'B')
,(1234,'A')
,(1235,'C');


DECLARE @PivotColumns VARCHAR(MAX)=STUFF(
(
SELECT DISTINCT ',[ID:' + CAST(ID AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + ']'
FROM TestTbl
FOR XML PATH('')
),1,1,'');

DECLARE @SqlCmd VARCHAR(MAX)=
'
SELECT p.*
FROM
(
    SELECT DISTINCT CC
          ,COUNT(CC) OVER(PARTITION BY ID,CC) AS CountCC
          ,''ID:'' + CAST(ID AS VARCHAR(10)) AS ColumnName
    FROM TestTbl AS tbl
) AS x
PIVOT
(
    MIN(CountCC) FOR ColumnName IN(' + @PivotColumns + ')
) AS p
';


EXEC(@SqlCmd);

DROP TABLE TestTbl;
```

The Result:

```
CC  ID:1234 ID:1235
A   6       NULL
B   3       3
C   1       3
```

Comment: sorry to say Dynamic SQL is out the window on this one, the software the client uses to pull the information does not allow for temporary tables, updates, inserts or deletes.

Comment: @AnonYmouse, No temp table, no update, insert or delete. These commands are just to create a test scenario... There is a Sql-Server tag and a request which is impossible to fullfill without dynamic SQL (no way to create dynamic column names, unless your IDs are fixed and known and we might use a fix list of column headers here). Either build the statement in the client's application, or pull the data as a list and prepare the PIVOT in the presentation layer.

Comment: @AnonYmouse, I see you've just been around... And things are still not solved? Did you understand, that the dynamic approach does not need any "forbidden" command? If you need further help, please let me know.

Comment: I understood, the "example" is the data stored in two columns on the same table, ID and CC, the ID would fall into 3 IDS say 1,2,3 while CC could be ALC,BALC,DOLC,LOLC,TOK,KIK,TEK,ETC and I need to count if in (AL"C",BAl"C"....) and then a seperate count for TOK,KIK,TEK... and it has to be where in or when in.

Comment: @AnonYmouse, To be honest: I have no idea what letter codes you are talking about... You placed a question on SO, quite clearly articulated, with sample data and expected output. I gave you a solution which works **exactly** as you stated. For me this means: This question is solved. You should vote it up and tick the acceptance check. Then you place a new question on SO, describe your new problem, add suitable sample data and expected output and within minutes you'll find people willing to help you. If you place me a link to the new question I will pop up there and join the helping armada :-)

Comment: except you ignored the base factor of I cannot use inserts, etc.

Comment: @AnonYmouse, no, I did not ignore anything... Fact is, that you do NOT need these commands at all. There is only one single way to solve your issue: dynmic PIVOT. This you can do with pure SQL, you need DECLARE and EXEC, nothing more, or you can build up the statement in your application and call it from there. Once again: The CREATE TABEL, the INSERT and the DROP TABLE is only to create a test scenario...

Answer (score 0):

I suspect I may have misunderstood your requirement, so please accept my apologies if this isn't the answer you are looking for for.

Is this just a case of conditionally counting rows, based on a combination of CC and ID?

**Example**

```
DECLARE @Sample TABLE
    (
        ID        INT,
        CC        VARCHAR(1)
    )
;

INSERT INTO @Sample
    (
        ID,
        CC
    )
VALUES
    (1234, 'A'),
    (1234, 'B'),
    (1234, 'C'),
    (1234, 'A'),
    (1235, 'B'),
    (1235, 'B'),
    (1234, 'A'),
    (1235, 'C'),
    (1234, 'A'),
    (1234, 'B'),
    (1235, 'C'),
    (1234, 'A'),
    (1234, 'B'),
    (1235, 'B'),
    (1234, 'A'),
    (1235, 'C')
;


SELECT
    CC,
    SUM(CASE WHEN ID = 1234 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)        AS [ID:1234],
    SUM(CASE WHEN ID = 1235 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)        AS [ID:1235]
FROM
    @Sample
GROUP BY
    CC
;
```

**Returned**

```
CC  ID:1234  ID:1235
A   6        0
B   3        3
C   1        3
```

The last record contains a different value in ID:1235 to your example.  If you can explain why this should 1 I'll take another look at my query.

Comment: This would work, if 1234 and 1235 are the only IDs, or at least if a known set of IDs exists and won't change... That's why I introduced dynamic SQL. At this stage the OP has left the scene. Hope he/she will come back to clearify...

Comment: @Shnugo I'm pretty sure my answer doesn't address the OP needs too.  If the required IDs aren't fixed s/he'll be better off looking at your answer.  Which doesn't require temp tables, as you quite rightly pointed out.